# ReactJS: setTimeout() not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having this code in mind:

```
var Component = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {position: 0};    
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        setTimeout(this.setState({position: 1}), 3000);
    },

    render: function () {
         return (
            <div className="component">
                {this.state.position}
            </div>
         ); 
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Component />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Isn't the state supposed to change only after 3 seconds? It's changing immediately.

My main goal here is to change the state every 3 seconds (with `setInterval()`), but since it was not working, I tried `setTimeout()`, which is not working either. Any lights on this? Thanks!

Comment: If you have `foo(bar())` then `bar` is **executed first** and its return value is passed to `foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling that seems correct, but not appropriate. Since the `foo()` here is exactly to execute `bar` after desired timeout. Or am I completely wrong and it executes right away, and only return value after the desired time?

Comment: *"Since the foo() here is exactly to execute bar after desired timeout."* Right, that's why you have to pass `bar`, not call it and pass its returns value. Did you expect the behavior of `foo(bar())` to change, depending what `foo` is doing? That would be really strange.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Do

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        this.setState({ position: 1 });
    }
    .bind(this),
    3000
);
```

Otherwise, you are passing the result of `setState` to `setTimeout`.

You can also use ES6 arrow functions to avoid the use of `this` keyword:

```
setTimeout(
  () => this.setState({ position: 1 }), 
  3000
);
```

Comment: Yeah makes sense and it's working. But isn't function() a function? So why would we need to bind it? I already tried and it's really needed, I just wanted to know why. Appreciate for your help :)

Comment: I don't get why you're saying it would pass the result to setTimeout, how does that not make this work?  What's the behavior in that case?

Comment: for those of you who prefer to use ES6 arrow functions: 
`setTimeout(() => {this.setState({ position: 1 })}, 3000)`
@PositiveGuy not sure if you've researched this on your own since this question was posted, but in case you haven't: Daniel's original example needs `.bind(this)` to restrict the `this` context to `setState` - otherwise, `this` will automatically refer to the context in which it is invoked (in this case, the anonymous `function` being passed to `setTimeout`). ES6 arrow functions, however, are _lexically scoped_ - they restrict `this` to the context in which they're called.

Comment: Doesn't work...
setTimeout(()  => {
        if (!this.props.logoIsLoading && !this.props.isLoading) {
          console.log('Will we happen?');
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            shouldUpdate: false,
            itemToUpdate: null,
            modalIsOpen: false,
            modalTitle: 'Add New Organization'
          });
        }
      }, 100);

Its in context of class syntactical sugar class Organizations extends Component {

console.log never gets console.log('Will we happen?'); Everything before it and after it is logged.

Comment: @juslintek define not work. please ask a new question if needed.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I use redux-saga and redux-store, might they be affecting my outcome?

Comment: @juslintek no clue. please ask a new top level question, not in a comment to my answer.

Comment: Pure GEM of an answer

Comment: Please don't. Use this instead: `setTimeout(this.setState, 3000, { position: 1 })`. [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working/66694391#66694391)

Answer (score 167):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ position: 1 });
}, 3000);
```

The above would also work because the ES6 arrow function does not change the context of `this`.

Comment: The ES6 syntax should be the accepted answer for best practices in React. Both will work, but this is more elegant and handles `this`.

Answer (score 26):

Anytime we create a timeout we should s clear it on componentWillUnmount, if it hasn't fired yet.

```
      let myVar;
         const Component = React.createClass({

            getInitialState: function () {
                return {position: 0};    
            },

            componentDidMount: function () {
                 myVar = setTimeout(()=> this.setState({position: 1}), 3000)
            },

            componentWillUnmount: () => {
              clearTimeout(myVar);
             };
            render: function () {
                 return (
                    <div className="component">
                        {this.state.position}
                    </div>
                 ); 
            }

        });

ReactDOM.render(
    <Component />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is a little old, but is important to notice that React recomends to clear the interval when the component unmounts: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

So I like to add this answer to this discussion:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

`setState` is being invoked immediately due to the parenthesis! Wrap it in an anonymous function, then call it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.setState({position: 1})
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Answer (score 9):

## You didn't tell who called setTimeout

Here how you call timeout without calling additional functions.

#### 1. You can do this without making additional functions.

```
setTimeout(this.setState.bind(this, {position:1}), 3000);
```

*Uses **function.prototype.bind()***

setTimeout takes the location of the function and keeps it in the context.

#### 2. Another way to do the same even by writing even less code.

```
setTimeout(this.setState, 3000, {position:1});
```

***Probably*** uses the same bind method at some point

The setTimeout only takes the location of the function and the function already has the context? Anyway, it works!

*NOTE: These work with any function you use in js.*

Answer (score 5):

**Your code scope (`this`)** will be your `window` object, not your react component, and that is why `setTimeout(this.setState({position: 1}), 3000)` will crash this way.

That comes from javascript not React, it is **js closure**

---

So, in order to bind your current react component scope, do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){this.setState({position: 1})}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Or if your browser supports es6 or your projs has support to compile es6 to es5, try arrow function as well, as arrow func is to fix 'this' issue:

```
setTimeout(()=>this.setState({position: 1}), 3000);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a 3 ways to access the scope inside of the 'setTimeout' function

First,

```
const self = this
setTimeout(function() {
  self.setState({position:1})
}, 3000)
```

Second is to use ES6 arrow function, cause arrow function didn't have itself scope(this)

```
setTimeout(()=> {
   this.setState({position:1})
}, 3000)
```

Third one is to bind the scope inside of the function

```
setTimeout(function(){
   this.setState({position:1})
}.bind(this), 3000)
```

Answer (score 3):

You did syntax declaration error, use proper setTimeout declaration

```
message:() => { 
  setTimeout(() => {this.setState({opened:false})},3000); 
  return 'Thanks for your time, have a nice day ! 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the function as a reference, no need to wrap it in an anonymous function or even bind it, which creates yet another function.

```
setTimeout(this.setState, 500, {position: 1});
```

---

## Enter *setTimeout*

It seems people don't realise that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` actually accept *optional unlimited parameters*.

```
setTimeout(callback, timeout?, param1?, param2?, ...)
```

The reason is to make calling the callback simpler, so instead of this

```
setTimeout(
  function(){
    this.doSomething(true, "string", someVariable)
  }.bind(this),
  500
)
```

You can write this

```
setTimeout(this.doSomething, 500, true, "string", someVariable)
```

#### Isn't that beautiful and elegant?

---

## Bug?

There is no bug in React calling setTimeout instantly, so if you were puzzled by it, consider this.

```
function doSomething() {/* */}

const a = doSomething() // immediately invokes and assigns a result
const b = doSomething   // stores a reference for later call

// call later
const x = a() // error "a is not a function"
const y = b() // invokes doSomething and assigns a result
```

And in your case with `setState`, this is basically the same thing.
When you register your `setTimeout` callback, you mistakenly immediately call it, where instead you should pass a reference to it.

```
function doSomething() {/* */}
const a = doSomething()

// wrong
setTimeout(doSomething(), 500) // This is basically the same as writing the `a` from above
setTimeout(a, 500)             // like this. See the problem? a() cannot be called later.
```

To fix it, you have three options.

1. pass a reference

```
setTimeout(this.doSomething, 500)
```

2. wrap in an anonymous arrow function which is transparent to `this`,
   meaning it captures the outer (parent) `this`.
   *note that this wraps your function in another function every time you call this*

```
setTimeout(() => this.doSomething(), 500)
```

3. wrap in a standard anonymous function, but since it comes with it's own `this`, you must bind it to the `this` of the parent.
   *note that this wraps your function in another function AND THEN binds it, which creates yet another function. That is two additional functions every time you call it.*

```
setTimeout(function(){this.doSomething()}.bind(this), 500)
```

Comment: Do we need to clear setTimeout during unmount of the component?

Comment: @kta If you use `0ms` delay e.g. `setTimeout(fn, 0)` then no, but for any longer delay yes. You don't want your timeout to run __after__ component unmounts. That would lead to errors or bugs.

Answer (score 2):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setActive(true), 5000);
    
  },[]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: Please explain little bit about answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ES6 syntax of set timeout. Normal javascript setTimeout() won't work in react js

```
setTimeout(
      () => this.setState({ position: 100 }), 
      5000
    );
```

Comment: Misleading and wrong...

Comment: It is indeed wrong. You can use a plain old `function()` instead an arrow function.