# setTimeout ReactJS with arrow function es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'd like to know how to use `setTimeout()` on ReactJS, because I'm doing this:

```
 timerid = setTimeout( () => this.reqMaq( obj['fkmaqid'] ), 2000 )
```

and it calls twice the function `this.reqMaq()`.

How do I prevent the first call? and just keep the call **after** the time?

Here it's the Component:

```
reqMaq (maqid) {
    return fetch(`/scamp/index.php/batchprodpry/${maqid}`, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then(req => {
        if (req.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server")
        }
        return req.json()
      })
      .then(json => this.processMaqReq(json))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('request failed', error)
      })
  }    

  handleChangeMaq (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
      let obj = this.state.obj
      obj['fkmaqid'] = VMasker.toPattern(event.target.value, "99-99-99-99")
      // if (timerid) {
      //   clearTimeout(timerid)
      // }
      // timerid = setTimeout(() => {
      //   if (!isRunning) {
      //     this.reqMaq(obj['fkmaqid'])
      //   }
      // }, 2000)
      const fx = () => this.reqMaq( obj['fkmaqid'] )
      timerid = setTimeout( fx, 2000 )
      this.setState({ obj: obj })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="maquina">M&aacute;quina</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" id="maquina"
                name="maquina"
                placeholder="Maquina"
                value={this.state.obj['fkmaqid'] || ''}
                onChange={this.handleChangeMaq}
                ref={node => {
                  input1 = node
                }}
                required="required"
              />
            </div>
    )
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: why is it called twice ? Do you call it on initialization ?

Comment: There must be some other context; on its own, this will call it once after 2s. Are you doing it in a lifecycle event? `render` method? Etc.

Comment: That `setTimeout` is being called on a `onChange` over a form field. What do you suggest? is it because of that?

Comment: I'm not calling it on init. I'm calling it on a `onChange`

Comment: First you should understand why is it called twice... Maybe you initialize the field ?

Comment: Your problem is not this code, it's the method that holds this code and any other code that calls that method. Based only on what you've told us here, the simplest solution is to use a flag `isRunning`, which you set to `true` when you start the timer, set to `false` when your timer ends, and don't allow starting of the timer unless `isRunning` is false

Comment: I didn't init the field @oliv37

Comment: @RafaelMora Please provide the full code of your React component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: setTimeout() not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working)

Comment: @Daenu I tried that also and doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (timerid) {
  clearTimeout(timerid);
}

timerid = setTimeout(() => {
  this.reqMaq(obj['fkmaqid'])
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I had to declare a var in the `state` and then use it in the method where the `setTimeout()` resides

Comment: If I get it right you want to debounce the execution of the reqMaq function, but currently you are only delaying it, so if you type two letters you will run that function twice. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
const fx = () => this.reqMaq( obj['fkmaqid'] )
timerid = setTimeout( fx, 2000 )
```

Comment: You should consider to include the full code of the component then, because the problem is not here

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `this.reqMak()` is being called twice is subtle.

In your example you use an actual call to `reqMak` to delineate your function pointer for `setTimeout()`.  The first time it is called is when you set up `setTimeout`; the second time is when `setTimeout()` runs, 2 seconds later.

The reason the suggested answer works is that it neither calls `reqMak` 'now', nor calls it later, as the function called by `setTimeout()`.  What it does do is pass an anonymous function `()=>{}` to `setTimeout()` for running later.  And when `setTimeout()` runs the function, 2 seconds later, the anonymous function calls `this.reqMak()`, once.