# How to delay componentDidMount API fetching in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am GETting data using Axios and wanted to make loading animation longer (for personal reason).

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var that = this;
    axios.get('api.something.io.json', {
        params: data
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        that.setState({
          axiosResponse: response.data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  ...
  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return <div>Waiting...</div>
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.state.axiosResponse.awesomeTitle}</h1>
      </div>
    );
```

Right now `Waiting...` shows up for a split second before main component renders. I would like to extend the `"Waiting..."` to last a little longer, about 2-3 seconds. I tried using [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working) on `componentDidMount` but it didn't seem to work.

```
componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(this.setState({isLoading: 1}), 3000);
  //do axios call here
}
```

I have also tried to stub the setTimeout inside `.then` call:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var that = this;
    axios.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', {
        params: data
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        setTimeout(
          that.setState({
            axiosResponse: response.data,
            isLoading: false
          })
          , 3000);

      })
  ...
```

None worked. How can extend the `isLoading` by 3 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts function as first argument:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.setState({
        axiosResponse: response.data,
        isLoading: false
      })
     }, 3000);
```

and not :

```
     setTimeout(
          that.setState({
            axiosResponse: response.data,
            isLoading: false
          }), 3000);
```