# TypeScript / ReactJS / setTimeout: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, settimeout, next.js

In my NextJS/React typescript app I'm using a setTimeout.

There is a bug in React apps causing setTimeout's to get called instantly, which I then found a fix in this answer here: [ReactJS: setTimeout() not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working)

Below is my code, but I'm getting the following typescript error on the `this` on `this.resetNotification`

> any
>   'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
>   Board.tsx(158, 7): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.

```
@bind
resetNotification(): any {
  console.log('resetNotification...');
  this.setState({ notificationClass: 'spin-in-notification' });
  this.props.setNotification('', false);
}

@bind
private handleNotificationClick() {
  this.setState({ notificationClass: 'slide-out-bck-top' });

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      this.resetNotification();
    }
    .bind(this),
    500
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it with arrow function on setTimeout for heredate parents props

```
setTimeout(
  () => {
  this.resetNotification();
  }......
```

Comment: 10 more minutes

Comment: Okey thank you, I thinked it can work but i didn't test it, we had luck!

Comment: @LeonGaban if Jordi's answer worked please mark it as the correct one, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use `function () {}` syntax, you can pass `this` as the first parameter to the function, along with a type annotation.  Like this:

```
  setTimeout(
    function(this: Board) {
      this.resetNotification();
    }
    .bind(this),
    500
  );
```

I'm assuming since the file is called `Board.tsx` that your component is `<Board>`.  If not, change the type annotation for `this`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer too.. +1 but I'm trying to avoid obvious Types, feel that would be too verbose in this situation.

Comment: Yeah for sure just thought I'd add that in case you _really_ wanted to use `function` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the function as a reference, no need to wrap it in an anonymous function or even bind it, which creates yet another function.

```
setTimeout(this.resetNotification, 500);
```

---

There is no bug in React calling setTimeout instantly, so if you were puzzled by it, consider this.

```
function doSomething() {/* */}

const a = doSomething() // immediately invokes and assigns a result
const b = doSomething   // stores a reference

// call later
const x = a() // error
const y = b() // invokes doSomething and assigns a result
```

And in your case, the *"bug"* you mention is basically the same thing.
When you register your `setTimeout` callback, you mistakenly immediately call it, where instead you should pass a reference to it.

```
function doSomething() {/* */}

// wrong
setTimeout(doSomething(), 500) // This is basically the same as writing the `a` from above
setTimeout(a, 500)             // like this. See the problem? a() cannot be called later.
```

To fix it, you have three options.

1. pass a reference

```
setTimeout(this.resetNotification, 500)
```

2. wrap in an anonymous arrow function which is transparent to `this`,
   meaning it captures the outer (parent) `this`.
   *note that this wraps your function in another function every time you call this*

```
setTimeout(() => this.resetNotification(), 500)
```

3. wrap in a standard anonymous function, but since it comes with it's own `this`, you must bind it to the `this` of the parent.
   *note that this wraps your function in another function AND THEN binds it, which creates a third function every time*

```
setTimeout(function(){this.resetNotification()}.bind(this), 500)
```

## Enter *setTimeout*

```
setTimeout(callback, timeout?, param1?, param2?, ...)
```

It seems people don't realise that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` actually accept *optional unlimited parameters*. The reason is to make calling the callback simpler, so instead of this

```
setTimeout(
  function(){
    this.doSomething(true, "string", someVariable)
  }.bind(this),
  500
)
```

You can write this

```
setTimeout(this.doSomething, 500, true, "string", someVariable)
```

#### Isn't that beautiful and elegant?

---

Also you should fix your `resetNotification()` function's signature to `resetNotification(): void` not `:any` as it doesn't return anything.