# I want to put a delay per map iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an event where I want to put a little time in between events.

```
  <div className="cards">
    {this.state.data.map((merchant, index) => (
      <CardRow
        merchant={{ merchant }}
        count={index}
        className={"card-color-" + index}
        key={merchant.id}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
```

I want to do something along the lines of

```
  <div className="cards">
    {this.state.data.map((merchant, index) => (
      <CardRow
        merchant={{ merchant }}
        count={index}
        className={"card-color-" + index}
        key={merchant.id}
      />,
  wait(5000) // Pseudocode
    ))}
  </div>
```

There's setTimeout, and async/await and I don't think either fits my use-case.

I am trying to do this in React.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working

Comment: Could slice your array and use interval timer to add new element to state instead. Not 100% clear what expected behavior is though

Comment: I ended up doing what the duplicate answer said