# scrollIntoView does not work on first load and after each refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx, js-scrollintoview

I am seeing a very strange behavior in my chat. Once the chat is opened, the scroll moves only a tiny bit down **only when** there are images in the chat. When there is **only text**, it goes all the way down. Also, if I close the chat and open it again, the scroll goes all the way down regardless of the content. However, If I refresh the page, the scroll returns to its weird behavior. I am puzzled as to why this is happening. Here's my code:

Here's how the chat starts:

```
startChat () { 
       
    
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";       
   
    
        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('Chats').doc(this.state.uid).collection('Messages');

        const query = ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(10)



        this.unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {                            

                            if (snapshot.empty) {

                                console.log('No matching documents.');
                                
                                firebase.firestore().collection('Chats').doc(this.state.uid).
                                set({
                                    name: this.state.displayName,
                                    uid: this.state.uid,
                                    email: this.state.email
                                }).then(console.log("info saved"))
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.log("Error saving info to document: ", error);
                                });
                            }
                                                  
                                snapshot.docChanges().reverse().forEach((change) => {                                  
                                  

                                if (change.type === 'removed') {
                    
                                console.log(change.doc.data().content)
                    
                                } 
                                
                                
                                else if (change.type === 'added') {                
                                
                                  this.setState(state => {
                                    const messages = [...state.messages, {id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()}]
                                    return {
                                        messages
                                    }
                    
                                })    
                                
                                setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom(), 2000)                                
                                
                                
                                
                                } 
                                
                                else if (change.type === 'modified') { 
                                    
                                                                        
                                    const filteredMessages = this.state.messages.filter(message => message.body.allowed === "yes")

                                   this.setState(state => {
                                      const messages = [...filteredMessages, {id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()}]
                                      return {
                                          messages
                                      }
                      
                                  })    
                                  
                                  setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom(), 2000)
                                  
                                  
                                  
                                  } 
                    
                                                                  
                                });
                                }, (error) => {console.log(error)});             
                    
                                
    }
```

Here's the scroll function:

```
scrollToBottom = () => {     

        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });      
       

      }
```

Here's the JSX of the chat:

```
<div className="form-popup" id="myForm">
                    <form className="form-container" onSubmit={this.chatFormSubmit}>

                        <h1>Chat</h1>

                        <label htmlFor="msg"><b>Message</b></label>


                        <div className="chatArea" id='messages'>
                            
                       
                            {
                               
                                this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                                return message.body.uid === this.state.uid && !message.body.imageUrl
                                ?
                                <p className="message-sent" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                                : 
                                message.body.uid === this.state.uid && message.body.imageUrl 
                                ?
                                <img src={message.body.imageUrl} className="message-sent" key={index}></img>
                                :
                                <p className="message-received" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>

                                    

                                
                                })
                            
                            }      

                            <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
                               ref={this.myRef}>
                            </div>               
                           

                        </div>
```

And if the functions for closing and submitting messages to the chat are of any use, here they are:

```
closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
        this.setState({messages: []})
        this.unsubFromMessages();        
    }


chatFormSubmit(e) {
                  
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ writeError: null }); 

        firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Chats')
        .doc(this.state.uid)
        .collection('Messages')  
        .doc()
        .set({
            docId: this.state.docId,
            content: this.chatArea.current.value,
            allowed: "yes",
            timestamp: new Date(),
            uid: this.state.uid,
            name: this.state.displayName,
            email: this.state.email
            }, { merge: true })
            .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ writeError: error.message });
        })
            .then(this.chatArea.current.value = '')





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I figured it out myself. Instead of calling "this.scrollToBottom()" in setTimeout, I should have simply passed it like this setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom, 2000). That is why setTimeout was not working and the scroll stopped half way. Credit goes to Felix Kling's comment in [ReactJS: setTimeout() not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270422/reactjs-settimeout-not-working/36270461).